# Access a viewbag property in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am developing a web application , where i am using reactjs and MVC c#.

I would want to know if jsx is included in a cshtml , is it possible to access a viewbag property in jsx? i would have a object or id to be passed to jsx which will be rendered in the UI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ViewBag` is rendered and execute in the server side, react is invoked on the browser (client).
Your main options are:

1. Global variable -   In the razor (`.cshtml`) you can set a global
   object `window.param = ViewBag.param`. and access it from react.
   `const x = window.param`
2. Pass a value (primitives only) to the root element of react via a
   `data-attribute` and grab it before you call  render:   example:

   ```
       // razor (.cshtml)
           <div id="root" data-param="@ViewBag.param"></div>

      // react
           const root = document.getElementById('root');    
           const param =  root.getAttribute('data-param');
           render(<App myParam={param}/>, root)
   ```